# For a water in a beaker, is the surface tension different at center than at regions water touches the beaker?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

Is the surface tension at regions touching the beaker altered as a result of adhesive forces between water and glass?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the surface tension at regions touching the beaker can be altered as a result of adhesive forces between water and glass.

Surface tension is the cohesive force that holds the molecules of a liquid together at the surface. When water comes into contact with a solid surface, such as glass, the adhesive forces between the water molecules and the surface of the glass create an imbalance in the cohesive forces at the surface of the water. This results in the water molecules at the surface near the glass being pulled towards the glass, which can cause the surface tension to be altered.

Comment: Is there any experimental evidence that this is the case? Please give a pointer to a published paper or two (or a textbook) to indicate that the answer refers to consensus physics.

Comment: @Chemomechanics capillary rise(how plants transfer water to massive heights) is a example

Comment: Capillary rise can be explained by a constant surface tension. Your answer discusses a variable surface tension. I’m asking if you can provide peer-reviewed evidence for this claim. This should be easy to do if the answer reflects consensus physics rather than a personal opinion or AI-generated content, for instance.